# Does plugin's uninstall.php file have access to the plugin 's object?

Tags: plugins, uninstallation

I read on the codex that the best way to implement a clean uninstallation functionality to a plugin is by adding a uninstall.php file inside your plugin directory.

I'm wondering: can i use my plugin's Class instance data inside the uninstall.php file?

This is the code sitting in my uninstall.php file:

```
if(!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN')) exit;
delete_option('my_plugin_options');
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . $this->dbName;
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE `$table_name`");
```

I'm wondering if the table_name variable will be properly retrieved, or if i should hardcode it.

As per my tests, the table remains after deletion, so i guess i'l fallback to using a hook inside my plugin's file, unless i'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in my desktop, but I suspect it won't be retrieved.

But:

- have you tested it? Does the table gets droped?
- I'd say you need to declare *global $wpdb;*, isn't it?
- if you don't have any, a tool like [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) is **really** handy when developing
- anyway, this seems a case where is pretty harmless to hardcode the table name